Conditions for two linear transforms of iid random variables to have a symmetric joint distribution
Suppose $Z$ is a $T \times 1$ vector with i.i.d. $Z_t, t=1,2,\ldots,T$, and $E(Z_{t})=0$. Now given two constant $T \times 1$ vectors $a$ and $b$, define two random variables: $X=a^{\prime}Z$ and $Y=b^{\prime}Z$, where $a'a = b'b$.
My question is: under which conditions can we claim that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly symmetrically distributed? That is, $f_{X,Y}(m,n)=f_{X,Y}(n,m), \forall m,n$.
I know when Z is jointly normal, the claim is true. But I was wondering if there is a more general condition beyond normality.

Even if the distribution of each of the iid variables ${Z_i}$ is $N(0,1)$, you would need the vectors $a$ and $b$ to have the same magnitude to conclude symmetry (exchangeability) holds. Note that one consequence of such symmetry is that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution (which fails if $a$ and $b$ have different magnitudes, meaning different Euclidean norm).

@Michael Thank you, Michael. I just realized my carelessness as well. I just reivsed my post. Thank you again.

Are the $a$ and $b$ in  your first paragraph the same as the $a$ and $b$ in the second?

@kimchilover Thank you. They are not. I just edited the question.
